# Regular expression to get the Name from URL link

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Hyperlink field (aka column) in SharePoint 2010.

Say it's called `SalesReportUrl`. The url looks like:

```
http://portal.cab.com/SalessiteCollection/October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx
```

The hyperlink field stores values in two fields (the link and description).

What would be the RegEx if I want to get the `October2012Library` out of the Url?

I tried this but it's definitely not working:

```
@"<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>";
```

I also tried:

```
^(.*?/)?Forms/$
```

but no luck.

I think sharepoint stores hyperlink like this:

```
http://portal.cab.com/SalessiteCollection/October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx, some description
```

Looks like this has a solution. but what's the syntax substring get the list or library name ?https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40712/get-list-title-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow

Comment: have you tried the `Uri` class?

Comment: Not sure how to use Uri class in Workflow. I am trying to get the document library name from the hyperlink column.

Comment: hmm. none worked. May I can use the substring function to extract the document library name from the hyperlink column (or field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/

match's group[1] is the value you need. it gets the 3rd part (divided by /) in the url. if you need make sure it is followed by other parts, i.e. forms, add it at the end.

Comment: It gives me October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx as a result. I dont need anything after the /. How can i do this?

Comment: I had to create another variable in workflow to get rid of the remainder string. I used (/Forms.*) and now I have a Library Name.

Comment: can anyone suggest one complete regex instead of 2 fold regex?

Answer (score 5):

How about this (as Daniel suggested) :

```
string url = @"http://portal.cab.com/SalessiteCollection/October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
if(uri.Segments.Length > 2))
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[2]); // will output "October2012Library/"
```

you can add `.Replace("/", string.Empty)` if you want to get rid of the "/"

```
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[2].Replace("/", string.Empty));
```

Comment: That's better than my (now ex) answer... I always seem to fail to spot the member that makes it easy with `Uri` :-(

Comment: @Richard I always set a breakpoint after the instantiation then use the watch window to spot the interesting members.

Comment: All good until `Uri.Segments.Length < 2`. Perhaps `Uri.Segments.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()` so you get a `null` if there aren't enough segments,

Comment: Yeah... definitely cheaper than my verbose way of saying the same thing ;)

Comment: This did not work. I have a column in a list and column type is Hyperlink. SP stores hyperlink with description. string url = hardcode url wont work for my situation. also I can't use Uri in the workflow. May a RegEx that looks for Forms or forms and gets the library name that is right before the /forms and make sure not to include all the value before the library name.

Answer (score 0):

try using this `new RegEx("SalessiteCollection/(.+?)/Forms").match(<urlString>).groups[1].value`

Though it is a rough answer, you might have to make few corrections but I hope you understand what I am trying to explain.

Comment: site collection is a variable unless it is called SalessiteCollection.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this?

```
http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\/[a-zA-Z]*\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\/
```

http://rubular.com/r/LuuuORPRXt